# passing local pointer to function FatFs

Tags: c, pointers, fatfs

I have the following function in C:

```
char* AUDIO_GetFile(FIL* fil, DIR* dir, FILINFO* fno) {
    FRESULT res;
    res = f_readdir(dir, fno); /* Read a directory item */
    if (fno->fname[0] == '\0')} /* End of files */
       ...
    }
    ...
    return &(fno->fname);
}
```

However I need a temporary variable to keep old value and then return `&(fno->fname)`. I created local variable `FILINFO t_fno` and then pass it to function `res = f_readdir(dir, &t_fno);` everything is OK.

But if I wanted to use t_fno as local pointer and then pass it to f_readdir I don't get actual data but some random memory readings and program crashes on `if (t_fno->fname[0] == '\0')}`. I tried also initalizing `FILINFO* t_fno = NULL` but this doesn't help.

```
char* AUDIO_GetFile(FIL* fil, DIR* dir, FILINFO* fno) {
    FRESULT res;
    FILINFO* t_fno;
    res = f_readdir(dir, t_fno); /* Read a directory item */
    if (t_fno->fname[0] == '\0')} /* crash */
       ...
    }
    ...
    fno = t_fno;
    return &(fno->fname);
}


FRESULT f_readdir (
    DIR* dp,            /* Pointer to the open directory object */
    FILINFO* fno        /* Pointer to file information to return */
)
{
    FRESULT res;
    DEFINE_NAMEBUF;


    res = validate(dp);                     /* Check validity of the object */
    if (res == FR_OK) {
        if (!fno) {
            res = dir_sdi(dp, 0);           /* Rewind the directory object */
        } else {
            INIT_BUF(*dp);
            res = dir_read(dp, 0);          /* Read an item */
            if (res == FR_NO_FILE) {        /* Reached end of directory */
                dp->sect = 0;
                res = FR_OK;
            }
            if (res == FR_OK) {             /* A valid entry is found */
                get_fileinfo(dp, fno);      /* Get the object information */
                res = dir_next(dp, 0);      /* Increment index for next */
                if (res == FR_NO_FILE) {
                    dp->sect = 0;
                    res = FR_OK;
                }
            }
            FREE_BUF();
        }
    }

    LEAVE_FF(dp->fs, res);
}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your problem is, but;     'FILINFO* t_fno;
    res = f_readdir(dir, t_fno); /* Read a directory item */'  passes an uninitialized pointer into f_readdir().   That wil result in UB if that pointer is dereferenced for either read or write, ie. it's useless :(

Comment: @ThingyWotsit [Here is my problem](https://pastebin.com/iHPgNGXi). What UB means? The pointer is not dereferenced in f_readdir or any that needs `fno`

Comment: UB == "Undefined Behaviour"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [its docs](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/en/readdir.html), `f_readdir()` expects its second argument to be a "[p]ointer to the file information structure to store the information about read item."  This is consistent with the first use you described, wherein you declare `t_fno` as a local `FILINFO` structure, and pass its address.  It is **not** consistent with declaring `t_fno` as a pointer, leaving it uninitialized, and passing its indeterminate initial value.

The second way produces undefined behavior, which seems eminently reasonable given that the most charitable interpretation possible is that you've instructed the function to write data in some random place.  Even if it is successful in doing so, you cannot know what the effect will be, or whether the data will be unchanged when you try to read them back later, or whether you *can* read them back later.  C does not require or provide for you to reason about any of that -- it just declares the behavior to be undefined.  You cannot safely or reliably do the job that way.

As you observed, initializing the pointer does not help, unless (which you did not explore) you initialize it to point to actual storage compatible with a `FILINFO` structure.  The pointer declaration by itself provides only for the pointer, not for anything to point to.  Example:

```
char* AUDIO_GetFile(FIL* fil, DIR* dir, FILINFO* fno) {
    FRESULT res;
    FILINFO t_info;
    FILINFO* t_fno = &t_info;

    res = f_readdir(dir, t_fno); /* Read a directory item */

    // ...
```

Under most circumstances, I'd prefer not maintaining `t_fno` separately, but there could be viable reasons for keeping it.

Comment: Thanks, that make sense!